# Why wont this work? - def (function) not being called from main()

Tags: python-3.x

I need to be able to use classes, but trying to just get my simple code to work

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
 
class OutOfCountry7ViewModel():

    def pandas_conversion(self):
        #from csv import readers
        deImport = pd.read_csv("ooc-exceptions.csv")
        d1 = pd.read_csv("CS_Out_Of_Country.csv", encoding='windows-1252', parse_dates=True)
        d2 = pd.read_csv("sccm-devices.csv", encoding='windows-1252')
        d3 = pd.read_csv("CTLDAPRawData.csv", encoding='windows-1252')

        #pandas join magic
        lj_df1 = pd.merge(d1, d2, left_on="ComputerName", right_on="Name", how="left")
        lj_df2 = pd.merge(d2, d3, left_on="PrimaryUser", right_on="Employee Number", how="left")
        #lj_df = plj_df1d.join(lj_df2, lsuffix=)

        df = (lj_df1)
        #print(df)
        df.to_csv('CS_Out_of_country_tabl.csv', index=False,header=df.columns, encoding='utf-8')
        csv = 'CS_Out_of_country_tabl.csv'
        return csv

    def main():
        pandas_conversion(self)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

i keep getting an error, NameError: name 'pandas_conversion' is not defined

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: still doesnt work

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't make any sense. `OutOfCountry7ViewModel` is a class. Inside of it, you have a method, `main`, with no first parameter. You then try to call `pandas_conversion(self)`, but there won't be either a `self` or a `pandas_conversion` function in the scope available to that function. Your `if __name__ == "__main__"` is nested inside the class, which is almost certainly a mistake. Fundamentally, you need to learn how to write Python class definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do something like this? -

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
 

class OutOfCountry7ViewModel():

    def pandas_conversion(self,csv):
        ...

    def main(self):
        self.pandas_conversion(csv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    some_object = OutOfCountry7ViewModel()
    some_object.main()
```

Comment: i need to be able to do self. to call some html conversion down the road, but i need to go through my script first

Comment: Can you explain a bit what you mean when you say "I need to be able to do self"

Comment: my coworker created an app already with flask and is using the views/viewmodel technique, he has other variables that use the self. in his class. however in order for my script to run i need to be able to call it within the class and still assign it a variable to be able to call it again on the front end of flask

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
a = OutOfCountry7ViewModel()
a.pandas_conversion()
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try to remember the *semantics* and *indentation* of python.

- Unused import  *numpy*
- Class/Parent Class has no `()`, *Line 3*

```
class OutOfCountry7ViewModel(): #wrong

class OutOfCountry7ViewModel: #right
```

- There is no need of `()`

```
df = (lj_df1)
#if you using some func then you miss that func name
```

- If you're defining a method in the class you've to add instance `self`

```
def main(self):
        pandas_conversion(self) #wrong calling func with parameter
```

I think your code is wrong because in *PyCharm*, it says `def pandas_conversion(self):` may be static.
So, your code is incomplete, there is something missing that we can't find.

Comment: i appreciate your help, but if i everything inside the function, without the function is works fine